# Can a "burger" navigation go up again on menu click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this "burger" nav that appears after responsive with of 768 pixels - It´s working
fine but there should be a way to make the nav go up again (collapse) after
the user have clicked a button in the menu dropdown list

I was told to add $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('collapse') ... reverse
of .toogleClass('expand') but it doesn´t go up

There should be a way to manage this, right?

The user can click the "burger" icon again to close the menu - but making it go
automatically up after button-click makes much more sense

This is the code I have
HTML

```
        <div class="mobile-nav">
            <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
            <div></div>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="responsive-menu">
            <div class="menu-header">
                <ul id="menu-mobile-menu" class="menu">
                    <li class="burgerfont"><a href="#location">Where are we?</a></li>
                    <li class="burgerfont"><a href="#price">Prices</a></li>
                    <li class="burgerfont"><a href="#job">Apply fo job</a></li>
                    <li class="burgerfont"><a href="#beds">Beds</a></li>
                    <li class="burgerfont"><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
                    <li class="burgerfont"><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the Jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.menu-btn').click(function () {
        $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
    })
})
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".menu-item-has-children").append("<div class='open-menu-link open'>+</div>");
    $('.menu-item-has-children').append("<div class='open-menu-link close'>-</div>");
    $('.open').addClass('visible');
    $('.open-menu-link').click(function (e) {
        var childMenu = e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[1];
        if ($(childMenu).hasClass('visible')) {
            $(childMenu).removeClass("visible");
            $(e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[3]).removeClass("visible");
            $(e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[2]).addClass("visible");
        } else {
            $(childMenu).addClass("visible");
            $(e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[2]).removeClass("visible");
            $(e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[3]).addClass("visible");
        }
    });
});
```

This is a single pager so I´m using anchors - A individual page for each link would propably
reset the burger

**UPDATED** - CSS

```
.{display:none;}@media (max-width: 768px){.mobile-nav{display:block;z-index:1000;}

.menu-header {display: none;}

{}

  .menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
   }

    .menu-btn div {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: 64%;
      padding-right: 8px;
      margin-top: -0.50em;
      line-height: 1.2;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 200;
      vertical-align: middle;
      z-index: 99;
     }

    .menu-btn span {
      display: block;
      width: 25px;
      height: 4px;
      margin: 4px 0;
      background: #e86411;
      z-index: 99;
     }

  .responsive-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 57px;
    width:50%;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: #EDEDED solid 1px;
    border-left: #EDEDED solid 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(245,245,245,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(245,245,245,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(245,245,245,1);
    border-top: #EDEDED solid 1px;
    width: 320px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #000000;
    list-style:none;
     text-align:center;
       margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
   }

    .responsive-menu .menu-header {display: block;}

      .responsive-menu .menu-header ul {
        background: #fff;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;
          margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
       }

      .responsive-menu .menu-header li {
        background: #fff;
        float: none;
        line-height: 55px;
        width: 110%;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: #EDEDED solid 1px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        color:#e86411!important;
        list-style:none;
          margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
       }

        .responsive-menu .menu-header li:last-child {border-bottom: none;}

  .expand {display: block!important;}

  .responsive-menu .menu-header li .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style:none;
   }

    .responsive-menu .menu-header li .sub-menu li {
      border-bottom: none;
      line-height: 35px;
      list-style:none;
     }

  .open-menu-link {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
    color: #989DA1;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
   }

  .responsive-menu .menu-header li .visible {display: block;}
@media(max-width: 40em){  .responsive-menu, .responsive-menu .menu-header, .responsive-menu .menu-header .menu{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .responsive-menu .menu-header li{
    text-align: center;
  }

}

.burgerfont { font-family:'proxima_novaregular'; font-size:1.0em; text-transform:uppercase; color:#e86411; text-decoration:none;  }
.burgerfont a { color:#e86411; text-decoration: none;  }
.burgerfont a:hover { color:#f5cb32; text-decoration: none;  }


li.active a {
    color:orange;
}
```

Comment: can you post your css that is relevant to the html you posted so we can duplicate it in JSFiddle?

Comment: Hi Keith. Just updated the entry with the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the selector for the options `.responsive-menu a` on the function:

```
$('.menu-btn, .responsive-menu a').click(function () {
     $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
})
```

Check this **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87tgz0zc/1/)**

Comment: Nice!...this is perfect. Thanx. It´s much easier for the user. I´ve seen so many pages that force you to click the burger to hide it which is not user-friendly

Comment: Np mate ... @IngþórIngólfsson remember if you are using the same `ul` to show on larger devices the menu the functino still can change the display. To avoid that include the class `expand` on the media querie.